# How can I programmatically (CLI or code) retrieve the certificate used to sign an app bundle?

Tags: code-signing

I'm interested in knowing when the key used to sign one of my macOS applications has changed after an update.  How can I get information about which developer certificate was used to sign a given application/binary?

Note that I don't really trust the name on the certificate.  I'm worried about people who game Apple's processes to get issued a legitimate developer cert, possibly with a duplicate—or at least plausible—name on them.  I'm more interested in getting something like an SHA-256 hash of the developer cert used to sign a given binary.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but maybe look at `AppName/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources`. If you can't view it using TextEdit, try using an app like BBEdit.

Comment: @Sam Thanks, but it doesn't help, at least not in the general case.  For example, looking at this file for Valve's `Steam.app`, I see no indication of the key/cert used for signing.

Comment: [This GitHub Python project](https://github.com/comex/cs/blob/master/cs.py#L11) smells like it might dump the certs from a binary, but I haven't had the courage to install its deps and run it.  Seems like finding the `LC_CODE_SIGNATURE` command and digging down into the blob with the good stuff might be easier than all this.  [Here's an additional reference about code signing](https://engineering.linecorp.com/en/blog/ios-code-signing/), including parsing the blob with `openssl pkcs7`.